# Should outliers be excluded from generalized linear models?

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, glm

Is there best practice for including/excluding outliers from generalized linear models? I was under the impression that it is best to build a model, look at the residuals, then remove indices with the values with the largest residuals and refit the model. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I have seen where manually recorded or manually transcribed data has created a single data point orders of magnitude far from all other data points, sometimes this is not noticed until the regression analysis is performed. In such a case there is no other reasonable explanation for the (very out!) outlier and it can be removed from analysis or corrected after data review.